# Unit Test on overloaded method

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have been battling with writing some unit test for some of our code and I am struggling with this one:

We have a method that we overloaded and it is like this:

```
 Public Client GetClient(int productID)
 {
  //Some sql that evaluate a client

  if(!GetClient(clientRef,ClientTypeRef))
   Return Client.UnknownClient;
    //some other sql and codes
  Return Client.CustomerClient;
  }
```

The problem is how do I approach this, in my test I tried to add a mock to the `GetClient(clientRef,ClientTypeRef)` and returning an OK Client (anything other than `Client.UnknownClient`) to allow me to continue but I am getting a null reference? Is it possible to mock and test such methods, and how would I continue with this.

Comment: How did you mock `GetClient`? Could you please show the relevant bit of your code?

Comment: what testing framework are you using ?

Comment: Ellis: unit test @Paolo Tedesco: I extracted an interface where the GetClient is and mocked around it: `code` Private Mock<IClientService> _clientService= new Mock<IClientService>(); and then _clientService.Setup(x=>x.GetClient(It.IsAny<int>(),It.IsAny<int>()).Returns(Client.OK);`code`

Comment: ok i have been using N-Unit and in there you can use [TestCase(13)] to pass in a value to your method. so this give you a fixed mock up of your method
http://nunit.org/?p=testCase&r=2.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What mocking frame work are you using?

I use [moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/), to mock this method you would do something like

```
 _mockClientRepository.Setup(x => x.GetClient(It.IsAny<int>(),It.IsAny<int>())).Returns(Client.CustomerClient);
```

Basically this means that any integer passed to the method will always return Client.CustomerClient

Comment: Your solution make sense, I didn't flag it as an answer before but having now more experience than before I can confirm that it is the right aproach

Answer (score 2):

One of the reasons why unit testing has become so popular was that it was shown to encourage [SOLID design principles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29).

Based on the little piece of code you've included, I think your difficulty may come from the fact that your `GetClient(int productID)` has too many responsibilities so you're struggling to test them separately.

The way I understand it, you are:

- loading a client from the DB (by product Id?)
- checking (with complex logic involving more queries to the db?) what kind of client it is

Rather than mocking `GetClient(clientRef,ClientTypeRef)` so that you can test every logical path under it, I would encourage you (if possible) to try and refactor your code, so that you separate the loading of the client from the checking of the client's type and possibly also some of the logic you group under `//some other sql and codes`.

That should make it easier to test every piece separately, but above all would make your code more maintainable.

Comment: @Paolo Falabella: V good advice from you in fact I had previously considered that but being new to this Unit Testing, I thought there must be a way of doing this better, sure that the code is complex and that is what we call legacy, Anyway thanks for that

Comment: @JackM are you writing unit tests for a legacy application because you're trying to rewrite the application?

Comment: @Paolo Falabella: no this is part of a piece of software that was written but is used by different clients with different needs and configurations, so with time we happened to have done some backfit and small releases, as we are in phase of redeveloping we are having so many branches merged into the trunk and I ahve noticed that while fixing some bugs others are introduced and methods change and changed and changed again and It got the point where the software is working for one client and not working for the other, and a change for client a will make will make client B fall etc....